Using LASTools in QGIS
I am currently proceeding .las file in QGIS 3.36.2. To do this, I used Plugins to download LAStools and tried to use lasview function to visualize the 3D terrain. However, I got the following information of errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/40967/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\lastools\core\visualization_colorization\lasview.py", line 77, in processAlgorithm LastoolsUtils.run_lastools(commands, feedback)


File "C:\Users/40967/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\LAStools\lastools\core\utils\utils.py", line 64, in run_lastools
feedback.pushConsoleInfo(output.decode("utf-8"))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 4: invalid continuation byte


Execution failed after 0.07 seconds

I can directly input the .las file into QGIS3.36.2 by using Layer=> Data Source Manager, so the .las file should be correct.
Do you have any suggestion for how to solve this problem or how to proceed with an .las file?
